Does making an R2 bucket public and using a custom domain eliminate the need for a CORS policy to access its data?
I'm considering hosting video content on an R2 bucket and want to ensure seamless access to this content across different domains. My plan is to make the R2 bucket's access public and connect it to a custom domain. My primary goal is to embed these videos on an external website without encountering access issues.
My question is, if I make the R2 bucket access public (and utilize a custom domain for it), is this setup sufficient for enabling any domain to access its data directly (such as playing a video embedded on a website)? Or, despite these settings, will I still need to configure a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy to allow for unrestricted access across different origins?

Only certain request types need CORS and delivering video is not one of them.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors
